# hit a wall with d3.js line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm committed to learning d3.js but I'm having a very difficult time parsing different types of data in d3.js.

In this case it's just a simple .csv file for a line graph with tooltips  but I can not figure it out.

I would appreciate it if someone could take a look at my jsfiddle and offer some suggestions.
Thank you for your help!

```
d3.csv("http://www.corsproxy.com/dvl.thomascooper.com/data/mapleleaf.csv",
    data.forEach(function(d) { 

        //please see fiddle for complete code
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tommy6s/k6euLgrp/

Comment: Sorry if will this sound preachy (I'm just tryin' to help), but you should get in the habit of using `console.log` and `debugger`, and you'll have a much less frustrating time. For example, if you open up Chrome dev tools, you'll see that there's an error in the console. And if you check the stack, you'll see that it starts from `parseDate(d.date)`. Specifically, `d.date` is null, and that's because this stuff is case sensitive, and your csv data calls it `d.Date` (capital D).

Comment: Next, try `console.log(d3.time.format("%y-%m-%d")(new Date()))`, and you'll get `"14-12-10"` (today), instead of `"2014-12-10"`, which is the format you'd like to parse. Hence, `"%y-%m-%d"` wants to become `"%Y-%m-%d"` (capital Y), which is the way to do full year. That'll clear the error and solve some of the issues, but there are still other issues that are preventing it from computing the right x and y for the lines. Not sure what those are, but remember... `console.log` is your friend :)

Comment: Thank you meetamit. I'm going to try your suggestions.